# Pip upgrade failed with ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\xe2\x80\x93upgrade'

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I tried to upgrade pip with:

```
pip install –upgrade setuptools pip wheel
```

and got the following error:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
>
> ERROR: Invalid requirement: '\xe2\x80\x93upgrade'

After doing:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError:
>   [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc',
>   '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation
>   not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/markers.pyc'"),
>   ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.py',
>   '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/**init**.py', "[Errno 1] Operation
>   not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/**init**.py'"),
>   ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py',
>   '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation
>   not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/markers.py'"),
>   ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/**init**.pyc',
>   '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/**init**.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation
>   not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA/**init**.pyc'"),
>   ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib',
>   '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA', "[Errno 1] Operation not
>   permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-MzJySA'")]

How  can I fix that on OSX?

Comment: I would strongly suggest NOT using the system python 2.7 for what you are doing. Mucking it up will possibly cause problems beyond your desire to run python code yourself. Install python2.7 via homebrew or the provided installer from python.org. Use that to upgrade/install packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\xe2\x80\x93` is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode character [EN DASH U+2013](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) which is entirely distinct from (though vaguely visually similar to) the double ASCII minus character which commonly indicates an option name.

You want `--upgrade`, not `–upgrade`.

Sometimes e.g. blog platforms "helpfully" replace ASCII sequences like dashes, quotes, etc with "typographic" HTML equivalents which are more pleasing to the eye, but such substitutions should never be performed in `code` spans.

On MacOS, I would seriously caution against trying to upgrade the system-supplied files; sometimes, they are pinned to an older version for very good reasons, and regardless of that, you will be jeopardizing your ability to install future OS upgrades correctly if you muck with system files. Instead, try to use an isolated environment where you can upgrade individual libraries without touching the ones supplied by the system - the `venv` package installed with Python 3 is the baseline solution, but there are alternatives like the third-party `virtualenv` package (if you are really still stuck on Python 2! With condolences), `pyenv`, `miniconda` etc.

Comment: It *is* working. The new error is because you lack the permissions to do what you want. If you have `sudo` and know what you are doing, try that; but the feedback so far indicates you don't know what you are doing, so maybe spend some time understanding what it means before plunging ahead.

Comment: Recent verions of MacOS won't let you upgrade system files, and you basically simply shouldn't try. Maybe use a virtualenv instead. Then you can install exactly the versions you want without messing with and possibly wrecking libraries which your operating system requires, and sometimes requires a specific version of. But this is going far outside the scope of your original question; you should simply accept one of the answers here and then maybe ask a separate question about your new issue if you still need help.

Comment: This worked for me, I copied the "--" that appeared in the power shell of windows when suggested me to upgrade pip. After reading you, i decided to type myself the whole command. It worked when before it kept saying "ERROR: Invalid requirement: '––upgrade'" (In other words, the windows powershell uses a symbol that looks like "-" but it is not the "-" for upgrading. Such witchcraft.)

Answer (score 4):

Try running:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel
```

With double `--`